# In a VOIP application, when / where are codecs decided?

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk

I'm new to creating a voip apps for mobile devices.  I currently have an asterisk server set up and also an iphone voip app and an android voip app.  For both the iphone and android, I'm using linphone core library as my sip library.

Right now, I am able to successfully make calls.  Sometimes I have call quality issues like "crackling" in the audio, or parts of people's sentences are dropped.  As such, I'm trying to improve performance.

This is my first time investigating codecs, so I'm trying to determine which codecs are actually in use.   So my question is:

**When are codecs actually employed?  Do the phones use codecs to compress the audio to be uploaded and decompress the incoming audio?  Or does something happen on the asterisk server?  Or both?**

I haven't been able to figure out the answer to this question.  When I run the linphone command getAudioCodecs(), it gives me a list of available codecs, but not actually the one thats employed on a particular call.  For example, here's a var_dump of the function getAudioCodecs() in the middle of a call:

```
08-13 08:39:49.787: I/System.out(16358): codec:SILK 16000
08-13 08:39:49.787: I/System.out(16358): codec:speex 16000
08-13 08:39:49.787: I/System.out(16358): codec:speex 8000
08-13 08:39:49.787: I/System.out(16358): codec:PCMU 8000
08-13 08:39:49.787: I/System.out(16358): codec:PCMA 8000
08-13 08:39:49.797: I/System.out(16358): codec:SILK 24000
08-13 08:39:49.797: I/System.out(16358): codec:SILK 12000
08-13 08:39:49.797: I/System.out(16358): codec:SILK 8000
08-13 08:39:49.797: I/System.out(16358): codec:speex 32000
08-13 08:39:49.797: I/System.out(16358): codec:AMR 8000
08-13 08:39:49.797: I/System.out(16358): codec:iLBC 8000
08-13 08:39:49.797: I/System.out(16358): codec:L16 44100
08-13 08:39:49.797: I/System.out(16358): codec:L16 44100
08-13 08:39:49.807: I/System.out(16358): codec:G722 8000
08-13 08:39:49.817: I/System.out(16358): codec:GSM 8000
```

That's a lot of codecs...so how do we know which one is being used?

As for my asterisk server, my sip.conf has the following lines for each user:

```
allow=ulaw
allow=gsm
```

So does that mean I'm using GSM?  Because GSM is the only codec that appears in both my var_dump of getAudioCodecs and my sip.conf?

Here's the documentation for the linphone sip library if it helps:
http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone-javadoc/

**Additional Info**

OK, I found a few more interesting things.  I wrote this code into my android app:

```
//mLC is the currently active LinphoneCore object when receiving a call
LinphoneCallParams lcp = mLc.getCurrentCall().getCurrentParamsCopy();
PayloadType pt = lcp.getUsedAudioCodec();
String mime = pt.getMime();  // the mime value is PCMU
```

I noticed that the variable mime currently holds the value "PCMU".  I did a google search and i see it is associated with G.711.

**So can I assume that on the android app, it is the G.711 Codec?  If so, then how come even though I don't mention G711 in my sip.conf, it still allows it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Codec on asterisk will be selected in following order

1) Check which codec your device allowed in INVITE

2) Check which codecs you have in peer OR in [general] section. Peer have priority, but if you have no disallow=all in peer section codecs from [general] section also can be used. [general] section codecs can be seen by:

```
 asterisk -rx "sip show settings"
```

Peers codecs can be seen by

```
asterisk -rx "sip show peer peer_name_here"
```

3) Select first codec which match both section. Order as described in **asterisk's**  config.

On outgoing it do similar selection, if not match do transcode. Unfortanly asterisk currently not try select codec supported by both peers, so higly recomended use same order of codec or even single codec to avoid transcoding(decrease quality+hi cpu usage)

G711a and alaw is SAME codec(just other name)
G711u and ulaw is SAME codec.
transcoding from alaw to ulaw is lossless and very simple, so no quality loss.

Currently asterisk not support asymetric codecs, so both way will be same codec. To got more info use

```
asterisk -r
sip set debug on
```

Comment: in my case `sip show peer X` and `sip show settings` always have the *same* codec list. Any ideas what can be wrong about that?

Comment: I already give you idea. Check sip debug. You will know which side iniciated hangup.

Comment: In asterisk g711.a called alaw g711.u called ulaw